# SQL, PDO, and PHP - Conditioned rowCount() function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am running the following SQL PDO command in an Apache PHP server page:

```
$query = "
    SELECT
        id,
        building_name
    FROM
        campus
";

$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();          // HERE IS THE FUNCTION
```

Instead of returning the entire row count I'd like the `rowCount()` function to return only the number of rows where "building_name" = "IT House". I can't seem to find any information about this function, such as which arguments it expects, etc. Any idea how I can modify the function call in the assignment operation? Thanks in advance!

*NOTE:* I know I can condition the query via `SELECT` command, but I don't want to limit my query there. I need the query to represent all rows, but I need rowCount to only represent the desired rows.

Comment: If you want to count a subset of rows, but have a query return the full set of rows, then you need two queries.

Comment: @halfer I like this idea. Can I run two seperate queries within the same PDO session? I'm not at my workstation right now to try. Also, if possible, is it bad practice to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use as many as you need. I'd guess a page like the one we are using now, on Stack Overflow, probably uses 10 or 20 to render. One interesting feature of splitting data retrieval in this way is that, whilst you can do plenty in one complex query, it is sometimes quicker to use several simpler queries, even taking into account the multiple network round-trips to the database server.

Comment: @halfer thanks a ton, I think I will go with this suggestion.

Comment: In answer to your later question: I'd say it is good practice to have readable code that runs efficiently. Sometimes the two are in tension (code needs to be less readable in order to run faster, maybe) but, as above, it is perfectly normal to run multiple read/write queries in one page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the documentation for rowCount here:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Is there something else you are doing with the result that precludes you from only selecting rows with that condition?:

```
SELECT id, building_name FROM campus WHERE building_name = 'IT House'
```

Better yet you can just select the count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM campus WHERE building_name = 'IT House'
```

Otherwise you have to loop through the results to determine the number of rows that meet your condition:

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$num = 0;
foreach($result as $row) {
  if( 'IT House' == $row['building_name'] ) {
    $num++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes the other thing I am doing which requires all rows is writing / updating to a JSON file which stores all the rows for usage on the front-end. But the back-end, or this script, is also used to edit rows of the particular building name; this is a parameter received from a GET request from a web-form. I have not yet figured out a better way or place to update my JSON file so far, but this seems to work for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add the condition to the SQL statement, you would need to iterate over all of the results and then increment a counter based on whether `building_name` does equal **IT House** or not

Comment: That is what I am trying to avoid for simplicity. Is there no argument or condition I can write in PHP to filter the assignment?